# What difference between my compilation line and my makefile could cause the error?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I have previously write a compilation line which is working.
Howewer, my Makefile, which generates more or less the same thing, isn't successfully compiling.

Command line (working) :

```
sh3eb-elf-gcc -m3 -mb -ffreestanding -nostdlib -T addin.ld src/crt0.s src/BTKOM.cpp src/bluetooth.cpp src/syscall.s -o addin.elf -Iinclude -L libs/ -lgcc -lmonochrome -lfx -O2 -fno-exceptions
```

Makefile :

```
CC = sh3eb-elf-gcc
SRCDIR = src
INCLDIR = include
LIBDIR = libs
EXTENSIONS = c cpp s
LIBS = -lgcc -lmonochrome -lfx
WFLAGS = -Wall
CFLAGS = -I $(INCLDIR) $(WFLAGS)
LFLAGS = -m3 -mb -ffreestanding -nostdlib -T addin.ld -L $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -O2 -fno-exceptions
SRCS := $(SRCS) $(foreach EXT,$(EXTENSIONS),$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.$(EXT)))
OBJS := $(OBJS) $(foreach EXT,$(EXTENSIONS),$(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.$(EXT),%.o,$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.$(EXT))))
OUT = addin

all : $(OUT).elf

$(OUT).elf : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(OBJS) : $(SRCDIR)/$(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRCS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o

cleaner:
    rm -f *.o $(OUT).elf $(OUT).g1a $(OUT).bin
```

Generated lines from makefile :

```
sh3eb-elf-gcc -I include -Wall -c  src/MonochromeLib.c src/BTKOM.cpp src/bluetooth.cpp src/syscall.s src/crt0.s
sh3eb-elf-gcc -m3 -mb -ffreestanding -nostdlib -T addin.ld -L libs -lgcc -lmonochrome -lfx -O2 -fno-exceptions -o addin.elf MonochromeLib.o BTKOM.o bluetooth.o syscall.o crt0.o
```

Output :

```
BTKOM.o: In function `_main':
BTKOM.cpp:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `_memset'
BTKOM.cpp:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `_GetKey'
bluetooth.o: In function `Bluetooth::Bluetooth()':
bluetooth.cpp:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `_srand'
bluetooth.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `_rand'
bluetooth.cpp:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to `_memcpy'
...
```

Comment: [Read up on what the `-nostdlib` option does.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

Comment: @user4581301 I am aware of `-nostdlib` and I use it on purpose. It is working with my compilation line. Those instructions are defined in libgcc (`-lgcc`)

Comment: Got it, it's just `$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS)` instead of `$(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^` ...

Comment: Alright. I look like a fool. Ordering possibly. BTKOM.o is listed after the libraries, so the linker doesn't know it has to look in the libraries for stuff required by BTKOM.o

Comment: Ha! How's that for timing?

Comment: Try [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) as `remake -x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc) the built-in linking rule is defined as

```
$(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

`LINK.o` is

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
```

You should find it works by rewriting your makefile as

```
LDLIBS  := -lgcc -lmonochrome -lfx
LDFLAGS := -nostdlib -T addin.ld -L libs

$(OUT).elf: $(OBJS)
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Note that `-O2`, `ffreestanding` and `-fno-exceptions` are compilation options, not linking options (and I think `-m3` and `-mb` are as well).